# Remove Characters in R

Tags: r, string, data-cleaning

I have a large data frame with a character value in various columns and rows. The character is [subnet].

I am trying to get rid of it by writing the following code

```
new_data[]=lapply(new_data, gsub, pattern="[subnet]", replacement='')
```

However, it seems like although "subnet" is disappearing, I am ending up with 
"[]" for every instance of the character.

Any idea or fix would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to remove the square bracket because it is looking for character 's', 'u', 'b', 'n', 'e' and 't' instead of subnet `lapply(new_data, gsub, pattern="subnet", replacement='')`. Think about how we use `[a-z]` looling for characters from a through z.  Here, it is replacing with those letters specified

Comment: In addition to @akrun 's comment, if your character is really `"[subnet]"`, try to escape the brackets like so: `pattern="\\[subnet\\]"`.

Comment: ... or use `fixed = TRUE`.

Comment: Another option would be `new_data[new_data == '[subnet]'] <- ""`